# Find the color of text in an image using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have let's say the following image:

[image]

[image]

I've figured out how to get each line using EASYOCR. However, I want to know what color is of the text. I've tried to apply a threshold and use bitmasking, but what would I do if the background color is of anything other color than white?

As of the below comment, I have changed my code to this:

```
def dominant_colors(image,n):  # PIL image input

    image = image.resize((150, 150))      # optional, to reduce time
    ar = np.asarray(image)
    shape = ar.shape
    ar = ar.reshape(np.product(shape[:2]), shape[2]).astype(float)

    kmeans = sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans(
        n_clusters=n,
        init="k-means++",
        max_iter=20,
        random_state=1000
    ).fit(ar)
    codes = kmeans.cluster_centers_

    vecs, _dist = scipy.cluster.vq.vq(ar, codes)         # assign codes
    counts, _bins = np.histogram(vecs, len(codes))    # count occurrences

    colors = []
    for index in np.argsort(counts)[::-1]:
        # if index!=3:
        colors.append(tuple([int(code) for code in codes[index]]))
    return colors
        
dc = dominant_colors(Image.open('./mix.png'),2)
```

Now, it is working, however it is highly dependent on the image provided. When the FONTS AND WORDS are different, the results are quite different.

On getting the result, and on drawing back on image, it can clearly be seen that for some part, the detected is incorrect

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this problem almost 2 years ago and here's what I did to solve the issue.

I used **kmeans** on image to cluster it into `k = 2` clusters. The output would be 2 most prominent clusters namely the background and the foreground. You can convert this into a binary image by using `open-cv` binary thresholding. Now at this point you don't know which one is foreground and which one is background, so you use pixel count on the binary image. In my case the background always had more pixels so that was really easy to distinguish the text (foreground) from the background.

With this method, it doesn't matter which color is the background and which color is the foreground text, it also doesn't matter if you have minor noise cause it would cope up with it.

This technique solved it entirely for me, I hope it does the same for you or at least give you some leads.

Comment: how you implemented pixel count?

Comment: can you elaborate on converting with binary threshholding?

Comment: Hey thanks it is working but I'm unable to count the pixels to distinguish the text and background please some leads?

Comment: You can use the function `cv2.countNonZero` on your threshold images

Comment: @Arnav, images are arrays right. due to binary thresholding, you either have 1 or 0. counting pixels is just like counting 1s and zeros. does that make it clear for you ?

Comment: Thankyou veryyy much. However when I fit on the Kmean algorithm. I do not get exactly that color, but a color slightly different from the required one. Why is this happening?

Comment: Also, I am getting 2 results which are completely randomized, I have implemented pixel counting, however, what next I need to do to sort out which one from the Kmeans has higher amount of pixels?

Comment: can you show what you have been doing so far ? The background would probably have a higher pixel count

Comment: Basically, I have just got the word and then ran the algorithm on it. I noticed that it is highly dependent on the words and the font, for some fonts and words, background has less pixels than character pixels. Due to which I get the wrong result.

Comment: I've added my code in the question.